# Short for "I would like that we..."

Tags: paraphrasing

I wanna say the following:

> "I'd like that we had (something)".

Can I say:

> "I'd like we had (something)"?

I remember something like this from English classes.

Comment: the latter one is also correct

Comment: Both of them sound like "translation English," specifically word-for-word translation that does not sound idiomatic in English. See the answer by @Pixelomo for a good alternative. Or *I wish we had...*

Comment: "Wanna" is not standard English. You may also remember that from English classes. But you are on the wrong site. Try English Language Learners.

Comment: Colloquially in U.S. English one of the most common ways to frame statements of the type you are asking about is to say, "I wish that we had (something)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest form I can think of that feels better grammatically:

> "I'd like us to have.."